# Can I hide a parent div when I hover on it's child div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to hide a parent div when I hover over a div inside it.

```
<div class="parent" style="width:500px; height:800px;">
<div class="child" style="width:250px; height:250px; margin:250px auto 0 auto;">
</div>
</div>
```

I want to hover on the child to make it disappear both the parent and child div elements.

If there is a way even with jquery / javascript then please let me know.

I have 4 parent div and their respective child div and when I hover on another parent div then the hidden div re-appears.

Comment: `$('.child').hover(function() { $(this).parent().hide(); });`?

Comment: Isn't there some usability problem? should it reappear? when? how?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fApbK/

Answer (score 1):

You can use mouseenter event, then hide the closest parent like this

```
$('.child').on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).closest('.parent').hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/APEhX/)

Comment: Thanks but how can I bring it back. I have 4 parent div with their respective child div(s). I want to show that hidden parent when I hover on the other parents to hide them when I hover over their child div.

Comment: Then you can do the same thing but select the parent and use `$('.child').show();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.child').on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: and how can I bring back the parent div again when curser is in another parent div.

Comment: please provide some explanation to your code so that OP and Other User may learn

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use jquery **hover**.

```
$('.child').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/APEhX/3/)

**Note:** hover function can handle both mouseover and mouseenter and it is best to handle UI element.For example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/APEhX/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.child').hover(function(){
   $(this).parent().hide();
}, 
function(){
   $(this).parent().show();
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/JsmVm/